# How to set number of dropped down items in WinForms combobox?

Tags: winforms, combobox, height

Do you know if it's possible to change amount of items displayed in the combobox after it's been dropped down? (Something like a row count) Currently it shows only 8 items by default, and we all have huge screens and lot of items in the list, so it would be nice to show a larger combobox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you're looking for is [MaxDropDownItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.maxdropdownitems.aspx).